# How to match url to controller action

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having difficulty getting my my controller action, as this is currently matching the default route (I'm using a typical default route configuration)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Why doesn't my url get routed to this controller action?

My typescript

```
let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let update = new CollectionUpdate();
    update.collectionID = Number(this.collectionID);
    update.collectionName = "new name";

    let url = "/api/Collections/RenameCollection/";

    let json = JSON.stringify(update);
    debugger;
    return this.http
        .patch(url, json, { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
        result => {
            this.onRename(result as CollectionUpdate)
        });
```

My controller action

```
[HttpPatch]
    public Task<CollectionUpdate> RenameCollection([FromBody]CollectionUpdate update)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<CollectionUpdate>(new CollectionUpdate());
    }
```

Comment: What is the controller name?

Comment: CollectionsController.
I am able to route to that controller with the parameters setup differently (like a single int in the body and PUT) but this particular way isn't working.

Comment: What is the URL you're attempting to access?

Comment: /api/Collections/RenameCollection/




I've been able to reach my controller action using that url with a different combination of protocols, parameters (not sufficient to serve my purpose, though), etc, but this particular combination is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to a put operation worked.  I guess I'll just roll with that.

```
        [HttpPut("[action]")]
    public Task<CollectionUpdate> RenameCollection([FromBody]CollectionUpdate update)
```